# How to replace a value by a text in a select

Tags: postgresql

Assuming I have some values in column `col` of a table `t`. I know the exact list of these values, let's say it's `a`, `b` or `c`. I want to select these values and replace them by a text.

Display (select) `foo` if it's `a`, `bar` if it's `b` and `baz` if it's `c`.

It may be obvious and easy to find but I don't not know how to write my question to find relevant response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way is with a case statement.

```
select
    case col
        when 'a' then 'foo'
        when 'b' then 'bar'
        when 'c' then 'baz'
        else null 
    end as col
from t
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do the following.

```js
SELECT
    REPLACE(col,'a','foo') as col1,
    REPLACE(col,'b','bar') as col2,
    REPLACE(col,'c','baz') as col3
FROM t
```

Hope this works for you.